# How to delete the last character of text in canvas.create_text() in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

`self.canvas_textbox = canvas.create_text(290, 250, text='SOME TEXT', anchor=NW, fill="lime")`

How to delete the last character of text that is from `SOME TEXT`, I have to detele the last `T`.

I have tried the following code but it's delete the whole text.

`canvas.delete(self.canvas_textbox,"1.0", END)`

Please anyone help me in this !

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a question you asked just a few minutes earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive this you can configure the item you already have.

For this you need first the `itemcget` method of the canvas, then you slice the string and *insert* the string via `itemconfig` method of the canvas.

A working example of the use can be found here:

```
import tkinter as tk

def del_letter():
    old_string = canva.itemcget(c_txt, 'text')
    new_string = old_string[:-1]
    canva.itemconfig(c_txt, text=new_string)

root = tk.Tk()
canva= tk.Canvas(root)
c_txt= canva.create_text(10,10, text='SOME TEXT', anchor='nw')
canva.pack()
butto= tk.Button(root, text='del last letter', command=del_letter)
butto.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

Canvas a method called `dchars()` which you can use to delete characters of canvas text.

> syntax: `canvas.dchars(tagOrId, first, last)`

`dchars` deletes characters from a text item or items. you can specify from which index you want you delete. For example, canvas.dchars(tag, 1, 3) will remove the second, third and fourth characters.

To delete the last character of the text use `canvas.index(tagOrId, specifier)` to get the index of the last character. The specifier `tkiner.END` returns the last index of the string, then use `dchars` as shown below.

```
from tkinter import *

def update(event):
     canvas.dchars('text', canvas.index('text' ,END)-1 )
    

window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window,width=300, height=300, bd=0)
canvas.pack()

canvas_textbox = canvas.create_text(20, 70, text='Text', fill="red", tag='text')
canvas.bind('<Button>', update)

window.mainloop()
```